# String Formatting for Integers c#

Tags: c#, string-formatting, integer

I have a class that contains two strings, one that reflects the current year and one that represents some value.  These fields are combined based on a format (uses string.format) that is specified by the user.  IMPORTANT: The user entered data used to be generated so it was always an integer and we didn't have to worry about this.

Our default format is "{0}-{1:000}".  However, now that the user specified data is a string it does not want to format appropriately.  Here is an example:

The user enters 12 as there required data.  When formatting, instead of displaying 2011-0012, it is only displaying 2011-12.  How can I make sure that the 0's are added without doing some crazy loop that will append the 0's or attempting to parse the number (assuming that it is a number.  There should only be enough 0's to equal a string of length 4)?

Here is what I have tried as a format:

"{0}-{1:0000}" -> the original format when the user was forced to enter numbers.
"{0}-{1:D4}"
"{0}-{1:N4}"

Comment: There is a validation process that makes sure that the entered data matches the format.  If it doesn't, we forget about the 0's and simply put 2011:aa. My issue really comes from wanted to keep the system as much like the old one as I can, especially if we are generating the data ourselves (we always use number)

Comment: What does **2011-0012** represent exactly?

Comment: the year and then a sequence number that can be specified or generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`string.PadLeft()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx):

```
string output = string.Format("{0}-{1}", "2011", input.PadLeft(4, '0'));
```

Comment: The issue with this is that it will always add four 0's to the end (unless I'm wrong).  The string needs to be a length of four.  So that means if the user enters 123 then the resulting string should be 0123.  Though, I could always get the length and find out how many 0's to add that way.  If the default format changes though, then that is hard coded which is why it is better to know HOW to use a string format to achieve this.

Comment: @The Sheek Geek best look at Padleft a bit closer. It guarantees a minimum size using the padding, and doesn't add extra chars unless it has to. This approach is good unless you can have negative integers.. in that case you will see some wierdness, like "-3" changing to "00-3"

Comment: @TheSheekGeek - String.Format might not be the best solution for this task.  As BrokenGlass pointed out....**string.PadLeft()** is better for the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string.PadLeft` to add the zeros to the left, or use `int.TryParse` to attempt conversion to an integer. The latter will double up as your validation check.